# How to catch ".model" in perl

Tags: perl

My input file has content like this one:

```
1.1 CORE VT MODEL                             
.model ABC
model selector
```

I used this code to catch ".model" string

```
if ($array=~ "\.model")
```

but my output file catch all "model" string in my input file.
So how can i catch ".model" string in my input file?
Thank you so much

Comment: Basic regex stuff. Please read [perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

Comment: thank you so much. it is very useful for a fresher like me (y)

Answer (score 5):

Make the thing you're matching against a regular expression rather than a double-quoted string:

```
$array =~ /\.model/;
```

Otherwise perl will first process the double-quoted string, unescaping the escaped dot, then pass the string ".model" to the regex compiler.

Comment: If `.model` is always at the beginning of a string, best to use `^\.model`.

Comment: thank you so much, it is so useful with a fresher like me. (y)